# running selenium junit4 test suite tests multiple times

Tags: selenium, junit4

I have a test suite.  I'd like to execute this entire test suite 1000 times.  I have googled and looked everywhere and I can't seem to figure this out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!  If it would be easier to switch to testng, I will.

```
package com.bpms.tests;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ 
                InitiateBuyPlan.class,
                AddItemsToBuyPlan.class,
                ReviewBuyPlan.class,
                ApproveBuyPlan.class,
                ManageQuoteSolicitation.class,
                StartQuote.class,
                ReviewQuote.class,
                RecordInterestInQuotes.class,
                ReviewCountryBuyIn.class,
                CompleteItemInfo.class,
                ReviewItemInformation.class,
            })
public class SuiteAllTests
{

}
```

Comment: Just write a batch file that executes everything 1000 times?

Comment: I'm using eclipse to run the suite.

Comment: Pick the right tool for the right job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to build the test case programatically than via annotations

```
import org.junit.runners.AllTests;
import junit.framework.TestSuite;
import junit.framework.Test;

@RunWith(AllTests.class)
public final class SuiteAllTests {

  public static TestSuite suite() {
    TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
    for (int i= 0; i<1000; i++) {
      suite.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter(XXX.class));
      suite.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter(YYY.class));
    }
    return suite;
  }
}
```

Just replace XXX and YYY with the classes you have in your annotations.

Comment: Seems to be a problem with the above code.  I'm getting an error in the "public final class TestSuite"...   --> "The public type TestSuite must be defined in its own file"

Comment: Im guessing you copy and pasted my code in to your old file right? if you do that then rename the class to what the file is called...

Comment: Oh goodness, I should have known that!  Thank you, worked perfectly!